# How to get currently running project from Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to create a VS extension and I need to know the currently executing project (for example, if someone is building a Xamarin.Android app and they have deployed it, I need the Xamarin.Android project).  Further, I need to know the output directory of that project (so I can get some binaries from it).  Can anyone help me with this?

I've tried using [IVsSolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.aspx), and [DTE2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.dte2.aspx) (among other related things), but haven't found anything that tells me what is currently running.

Thanks

Comment: You are aware you can have multiple start up projects (and thus "running", whatever that means) in a solution?

Comment: Yes of course I'm aware of this.  An answer for how to get the output directory of multiple running projects would work too.  I'm not sure why "running" is unclear, if you have three Console applications waiting for input, then you have three Console applications running

Answer (score 2):

To know the output build folder of a project using automation (EnvDTE.Project), see:

[HOWTO: Get the output build folder from a Visual Studio add-in or macro](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2009/MZ2009015.aspx)

To get the solution startup projects using automation see:

[DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutionbuild.startupprojects.aspx)

Native VS services are somewhat more limited in this area than automation:

[IVsSolutionBuildManager.get_StartupProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionbuildmanager.get_startupproject.aspx)

The EnvDTE.Debugger object has properties to get the active process, etc:

[Debugger Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debugger.aspx)